# RDLC: How to show external images in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, reportviewer, rdlc

using a ReportViewer to show my reports: I have a RDLC with a parameter for an external image path.
the image is saved on the server.

Parameter value =

```
"file:///" + Server.MapPath("~/images/img.png")
```

this works on all other browsers but on IE it does not, however, if I export to PDF the image is visible.

Any ideas why this could be?

PS: I also tried using the complete URL of the image to no avail.

tested image url by posting in on the browser, url is fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    string imagePath = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/images/img.png")).AbsoluteUri;

    ReportParameter parameter = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", imagePath);

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried it, but no success. works fine on all other browsers, but refuses to show the image on IE